# If Else in Angular 4 for routerLink

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use my anchor tag's routerLink based on certain conditions at html page.
I have 2 flags IsService and IsUser, the routerLink will set based on these flags,

```
<a routerLink="/services" class="navbar-brand">Our Services</a>
```

Please tell me how can I achieve it by If Else.

Comment: So, you want to know how to use NgIf? https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible with the `*ngIf` directive, e.g.

```
<span *ngIf="isUser">
    <a routerLink="user">User</a>
</span>
<span *ngIf="isService">
    <a routerLink="service">Service</a>
</span>
```

If you do not want a span-tag (for css. reasons) you can use a `<ng-container>`-tag for this.

Comment: Or you could just put the ngIf on the <a> tags.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of ways to do that:

- *ngIf
- [routerLink]="yourFunction(variable)"
- [routerLink]="statement?['/foo']:['/bar']" (notsure for this one)

Answer (score 0):

Try not binding it, don't use [routerLink], user router link only, and URL path as a string, like below.

use this way

```
<span routerLink='{{ ($number>0)?"/urlPath":"#"}}' ></span>
```